# Monitor doesn't work with desktop PC. Works fine with laptop. Components seems to be fine

Tags: display, video, graphics-card, hdmi, vga

Recently i built new system from following components:

- MSI 760GMA-P34 (FX) mobo,
- AMD FX-4300 4-Core FX Series,
- 2GB Gigabyte GT 640 HD Series video card,
- 2 x 8 GB DDR3 Patriot (plugged in only one stick)
- and Acer S235HL 23 inch monitor.

2 days after connecting everything, setting up and installing windows 7 the system was working fine (except 2nd stick of ram, which was removed after few tries to install windows, always got blue screen.)

On 3rd day i rebooted computer (after some windows updates), monitor switched off and didn't turn on back again. Computer starts, monitor gives "No signal" message. Video card's fan working. Now, what i have tried:

- Cleared CMOS (unplugged CMOS battery for 30 mins, systemboard doesn't have reset button/plug/switch)
- Monitor connected to my laptop through HDMI and VGA ports works fine.
- Monitor connected to another ancient laptop through VGA port works fine.
- Monitor connected through HDMI and VGA to video card doesn't work.
- Monitor connected through VGA to internal video adapter doesn't work.

Mainboard, CPU and Video card sent to service center and reported to be fine.
Unfortunately i don't have chance to get another monitor or desktop pc.
Any ideas?

UPD: Is there a chance that cheap PSU is the reason? If so, how it can be explain that even onboard video doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried to connect your monitor to your motherboard VGA, while removing your video card from your system ?

Comment: Yes, i removed as much components as possible, like hdd, cd-rom. Tried connecting to internal vga card with removed video adapter, doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried a different monitor on your new build ?

Comment: Like i wrote before, i don't have a chance at moment to get another monitor. Closest friends have only laptops.

Comment: Can you still see BIOS POST screen? (RAM check, HDD connected, etc) If yes, there is a possibility that your windows somehow ends up with a screen resolution that your monitor can't handle. Some monitor will throw a message saying display is out of sync (or something to that). If you can still see BIOS POST messages, press F8 lots of time, and try to enter Safe Mode. If you can't even see BIOS messages.. then this comment is moot.

Comment: No. Monitor simply doesn't react when i turn on computer.

Comment: I've had this problem before and it turned out to be my PSU. Make sure all power connections are connected. If they are already, then it could just be dying.

Comment: How did you find out this? And i believe everything was connected properly, it was fine for 2 days and there was only "molex" connectors left.